# How to exit running event-triggered Cloud Function from within itself?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to terminate and exit running cloud function. Function was triggered by Firestore event. What are some ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some reasons why you want a Cloud Function to terminate itself, for example, to avoid an infinite loop or infinite retries.

[To avoid infinite retry loops](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#set_an_end_condition_to_avoid_infinite_retry_loops), set an end condition. You can do this by including a well-defined end condition, *before* the function begins processing.

A simple yet effective approach is to discard events with timestamps older than a certain time. This helps to avoid excessive executions when failures are either persistent or longer-lived than expected.

Events are delivered at least once, but a single event may result in multiple function invocations. Avoid depending on exactly-once mechanics and write [idempotent functions.](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions)

Note that updating the function-triggering Firestore document may create subsequent update events, which may cascade into an infinite loop within your function. To solve this problem, use trigger types that ignore updates (such as `document.create`), or configure your function to only write to Firestore if the underlying value has changed.

Also, note the [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#limitations) for Firestore triggers for Cloud Functions.

You might also want to check this [example](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-concepts-node-termination) about Cloud Function Termination.
Do not manually exit a Function; it can cause [unexpected behavior](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#do_not_manually_exit).